# I can't submit my app through Application Loader?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

This is the first time ever I upload an App and I'm getting crazy, I open Application Loader and follow the steps, I select an ipa file and then I get the following errors:

[image]

What I understand is that I'm missing some kind of certificate or something like this, how can I fix this? If I try to upload my app trough XCODE I can't because:

I go to my Archived app -> Distribute -> appstore -> and it says that IM mising some identities, so...

If someone please help me and explain the process of uploading the app

Thanks!

Comment: Surely you can find an answer within the scores of existing questions on this error. And I'm sure you'll find plenty of help searching for the error on Google.

Comment: There are 2 errors. First, you sign your app with an incorrect certificate (should be Production Certificate); Second, seems your network has some problems ("Cannot resolve hostname"). Check your HOSTS file to locate any unusual entry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem it drove me insane to fix it.  Update your Xcode to 5.1.  I added this to my build settings to `plist`

```
    MinimumOSVersion = "5.1.0",
    UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = false,
    UIPrerenderedIcon = true,
    UIStatusBarHidden = true,
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original posters errors why has it been marked as correct? The errors refer to codesigning certificates and network errors